# Mongo DB : Implementing $not query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to implement following query from java code:

```
{ "Post Text" : { "$not" : /.*golf.*/i}}
```

my java code:

```
BasicDBObject not = new BasicDBObject();
not.append("$not", "/.*golf.*/i");

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("Post Text", not);
```

When I am running above query, getting this log:

> Cursor id=0, ns=journaldev.Rotunda, query={ "Post Text" : { "$not" : "/.*golf.*/i" }}, numIterated=0, readPreference=primary

extra quotes around the regular expression are creating problem. Can someone help me in fixing this?

Comment: Which diver version?

Comment: Using mongo version:  2.12.3

Comment: Sorry, no help from me then ... only doing 3.x

Comment: `"/.*golf.*/i"` won't be treated as a regex, you probably need something like `not.append("$not", Pattern.compile(".*golf.*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));` (I don't know the java driver, so that's prob not 100% correct, but close)

Comment: @mtj - I switched to version 3.2.2. But still not able to fix it.

Comment: But with 3.x I can answer your question :-)    see below

Answer (score 0):

Using 3.x, you can use the Filters utility class to create various queries for you. In your case, you need the following construct:

```
 Bson myFilter = Filters.not(
     Filters.eq("Post Text",
         Pattern.compile(".*golf.*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)));
```

Using the 3.x driver to execute such a query is along the lines of:

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
 MongoCollection<Document> coll = mongoClient.getDatabase("test").getCollection("mycoll");
 coll.find(myFilter);  // do something with the FindIterable returned here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Pattern textRegex = Pattern.compile(".*golf.*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
BasicDBObject not = new BasicDBObject("$not", textRegex);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Post Text", not);
```

When you pass a pattern, mongo driver automatically takes care of making it a regex. If you debug and see the code it will run with `"$regex"`.

Hope this solves the problem